# Can we align Nested/sub list without indentation using Itext 7? Is there a way to achieve this using Itext 7 List APIs?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext7

Here is the sample HTML, can observe the difference between having "display and padding" styles  with and without.

Expecting the same result in Itext7.

Considering a List with one level of nesting, expecting child to be rendered at same level as its parent without indentation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ol.a {  list-style-type: decimal;  }
ol.b {  list-style-type: lower-roman;  display:inline;  padding:0px;  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Lists</h2>
  <p>Example of Flat Simple lists:</p>
  <ol class="a">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li> 
      <ol class="b" >
        <li>Sub Item 1</li>                  
        <li>Sub Item 2</li>           
      </ol>   
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected Result:

```
 1.Item 1
 2.Item 2
 i.Sub Item 1
ii.Sub Item 2
 3.Item 3
```

I need same output as the expected output given.

Current Attempt:

This is the code I am using right now but it is giving intended output

```java
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("results/listIndent.pdf");

//Initialize PDF document
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

// Initialize document
Document document = new Document(pdf);

PdfFont font = dfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
// Add a Paragraph
document.add(new Paragraph("List using iText7:").setFont(font));

List topLevel = new List(ListNumberingType.DECIMAL);

ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
item1.add(new Paragraph().add("Item 1"));

List secondLevel = new List(ListNumberingType.ROMAN_LOWER);
secondLevel.add("Sub Item 1");
secondLevel.add("Sub Item 2");

item1.add(secondLevel);
topLevel.add(item1);
topLevel.add("Item 2");
topLevel.add("Item 3");

document.add(topLevel);
document.close();
```

Comment: really quickly, have you checked the com.itextpdf.layout.element.List class?

Comment: Thanks for your response.... Yes, could generate nested list using List API. 

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
 List topLevel = new List();
 ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
 item1.add(new Paragraph().add("Item 1")); 
 List secondLevel = new List();
 secondLevel.add("Sub Item 1"); 
item1.add(secondLevel);
topLevel.add(item1);
document.add(topLevel);

Styling like padding or some formatting would help to aligh all items at same level.

Comment: Hi @jeevitha, can you edit your question to include the code sample from the comment and add an illustration of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexeySubach have updated my question. Hope this explains.

Comment: @AlexeySubach Itext5  allows creating a sublist by adding a List to another List. With Itext5, above requirement can be resolved naturally.                                      This feature is not supported in Itext7, sublist can be created only by adding the List to ListItem. Is there any documentation on why this feature is removed/deprecated.